# Erro no get do Axios - React Native

Tags: react-native, http-request, axios

Estou fazendo um curso de React Native e não estou conseguindo fazer uma requisição HTTP usando o axios.

Esse é o meu código:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { View } from 'react-native'

import axios from 'axios'
import Itens from './Itens'

class ListaItens extends Component {
  componentWillMount () {
    axios.get('http://faus.com.br/recursos/c/dmairr/api/itens.html')
      .then(response => { console.log(response) })
      .catch((error) => console.log('Erro ao recuperar os dados ' + error))
  }
  render () {
    return (
      <View>
        <Itens />
        <Itens />
        <Itens />
      </View>
    )
  }
}
export default ListaItens
```

E o retorno do erro no catch é apenas **Network Error**

Vi que algumas pessoas tiveram o problema resolvido quando o serviço a ser contactado era no localhost

Estou utilizando o emulador do Android para fazer os testes e não sei se alguma configuração tem que ser feita nele para que a requisição funcione, mas consigo usar a internet com ele normalmente.

Comment: Você pode testar online em: https://snack.expo.io/@sant0will/sponaneous-nachos. Aparentemente esta chegando certo no console.log. Talvez esse Network error seja por conta de não estar conectado a internet.

Comment: Está fazendo essa requisição usando uma conexão wireless? Exemplo: no seu pc/notebook, está conectado a uma rede wi-fi ao invés de cabeada. Você está mesmo conseguindo usar a internet no emulador (ex: pelo Google Chrome)? - Está fazendo aquele curso da Udemy que cria uma lista de produtos né? :)

Comment: Isso mesmo, @Renan. É o curso da Udemy.
Estou conectando pela wifi e conseguindo usar a internet pelo emulador.
Acesso qualquer site normalmente.

Comment: Então é diferente do problema que tive, no meu caso eu não conseguia acessar nenhum site, conexão zero. Resolvi criando um batch para limpar os dados do emulador e subir o emulador definindo o dns-server. `emulator.exe -avd Nexus_5_API_27 -wipe-data` e `emulator.exe -avd Nexus_5_API_27 -dns-server 8.8.8.8`. Pode fazer um teste usando esse segundo comando e, alterando `Nexus_5_API_27` pelo emulador que possui.

Comment: Tem certeza que seu Endpoint está cert? **http://faus.com.br/recursos/c/dmairr/api/itens.html**
Por que ele deveria estar assim eu acho
**http://faus.com.br/recursos/c/dmairr/api/itens**